# How can I create a two column combobox on a userform in Excel VBA using the first two columns of a table?

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I am looking to generate a combobox in a userform that pops up from clicking on a command button on my excel spreadsheet.  The purpose is to select a date and time (including time in case there are multiple entries for a specific date) from the combobox then click an "Complete Action" command button on the form to change the value from "No" to "Yes" in a cell at the end of the row of the selected entry.

---

From the research that I have done so far, this was the only code I was able to comprehend enough to enter in, but I do not get the display results that I was hoping for.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim v, e
With Sheets("Phone Log").Range("B9:C76")
    v = .Value
End With

With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    .comparemode = 1
    For Each e In v
        If Not .exists(e) Then .Add e, Nothing
    Next
    If .Count Then Me.combobox1.List = Application.Transpose(.keys)
End With


End Sub
```

---

Can someone please help with the code to display the dropdown list of the non-blank rows so that the two columns of reference data shows aligned and then take the selected row and change the cell value several columns to the right once the user clicks the "Complete Action" command button?

---

I would also be open to the combobox/user form being a separate sub so that I could use it as just selecting the row and running separate functions from command buttons that collect the user selected date.

TIA  ~Decoy

Comment: It's hard to visualize what you are trying to achieve. If you want to populate the combobox with non-blank values, change your IF condition to: If Not .exists(e) And Not IsEmpty(e) Then .Add e, Nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you need, but it should work (i tried it).

Tried to make it easy to read:

```
Option Explicit

Private Dic As New Scripting.dictionary 'needs a reference to "Microsoft scripting Runtime" in VBE>Tools>Reference

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim h$
Dim i&
h = Me.ComboBox1.Value
If h = vbNullString Then Exit Sub
i = Dic(h) 'converts to a Long in this case
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Phone Log").Cells(i, 3).Value2 = "YES" '3 is the "C" Column
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim v() 'needs to be a variant
Dim e$ 'is actually a string
Dim i& 'that's a Long

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Phone Log").Range("B1:B76") 'i only start at 1, because else i would need to be i-8 later on
    v = .Value 'do NOT use .value2 in case of dates, or currencys
End With

'Set Dic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
With Dic
   ' .comparemode = 1 'didn't find help on this one, not needed i guess
    'For Each e In v
    For i = 9 To 76
       e = v(i, 1)
        If e <> vbNullString Then If Not .exists(e) Then Dic(e) = i '.Add e,i 'or ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Phone Log").cells(i,2).address
    Next i
    If .Count > 0 Then Me.ComboBox1.List = Application.Transpose(.keys) 'i learned something here
End With

Erase v
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
Set Dic = Nothing
End Sub
```

EDIT : (sorry for the late answer, was beasy with my own stuff)

The previous code is for a one column combobox.

Here is an example on how to build a 3 column combobox (adjust code to your personal needs) :

```
With Me.Combobox1
    .ColumnCount = 3
    .ColumnWidths = "44;70;30"
    .ListWidth = 150
    .Clear
    .AddItem "*.XLSB"
    .List(0, 1) = "Binary"
    .List(0, 2) = "50"

    .AddItem "*.XLSM"
    .List(1, 1) = "Macro Enabled"
    .List(1, 2) = "52"

    .AddItem "*.XLS"
    .List(2, 1) = "Excel97"
    .List(2, 2) = "56"

    .ListIndex = 0
End With
```

Comment: Thank you, This works for the most part, but there are two minor problems.  1) If there are multiples of the same date, it does not load them separately, and 2) The time of the date does not show either.

Date of Call       Time of Call       Complete?
5/15/17                12:15 p,             no
5/15/17                  2:51 p,             no
5/19/17                 9:46 a,              yes

I would like to get both the time and date column to show in the combo box so the user knows which call they are actually selecting if there are multiples.  Otherwise this works perfect.

Comment: the use of a dictionary has its good and bad sides. One bad is all keys must be unique. Maybe add seconds to time.